# Spark distinct followed by join giving IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, indexoutofboundsexception

Trying to join two dataframes A & B. B has a distinct operation right before the join. Also one of the columns in B is joined on two columns in A. This specific situation is giving an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Anyone run into this situation before?

Details below. Thanks in advance!

Environment:

```
spark-shell standalone mode
Spark version 2.3.1
```

Code:

```
val df1 = Seq((1, "one", "one"), (2, "two", "two")).toDF("key1", "val11", "val12")
val df2 = Seq(("one", "first"), ("one", "first"), ("two", "second")).toDF("key2", "val2")
val df3 = df2.distinct
val df4 = df1.join(df3, col("val11") === col("key2") and col("val12") === col("key2"))
df4.show(false)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$reorder$1.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:233)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$reorder$1.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:231)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.reorder(EnsureRequirements.scala:231)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$EnsureRequirements$$reorderJoinKeys(EnsureRequirements.scala:255)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$EnsureRequirements$$reorderJoinPredicates$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:277)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$EnsureRequirements$$reorderJoinPredicates$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$EnsureRequirements$$reorderJoinPredicates(EnsureRequirements.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:302)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:294)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:294)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$prepareForExecution$1.apply(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$prepareForExecution$1.apply(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.prepareForExecution(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3249)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:725)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:702)
  ... 49 elided
```

**Update: Working Solution: Thanks @1pluszara!**

```
val df1 = Seq((1, "one", "one"), (2, "two", "two")).toDF("key1", "val11", "val12")
val df2 = Seq(("one", "first"), ("one", "first"), ("two", "second")).toDF("key2", "val2")
val df3 = spark.createDataFrame(df2.rdd.distinct, df2.schema)
val df4 = df1.join(df3, col("val11") === col("key2") and col("val12") === col("key2"))
df4.show(false)
```

Comment: The following worked. Still no clue on why I have to perform distinct on rdd instead of DataFrame.

`val df1 = Seq((1, "one", "one"), (2, "two", "two")).toDF("key1", "val11", "val12")`
`val df2 = Seq(("one", "first"), ("one", "first"), ("two", "second")).toDF("key2", "val2")`
`val df3 = spark.createDataFrame(df2.rdd.distinct, df2.schema)`
`val df4 = df1.join(df3, col("val11") === col("key2") and col("val12") === col("key2"))`
`df4.show(false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this:

```
val df3 = df2.rdd.distinct().map({ 
  case Row(key2: String, val2: String) => (key2,val2)
}).toDF("key2","val2")

val df4 = df1.join(df3, col("val11") === col("key2") and col("val12") === col("key2"))
df4.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+----+------+
|key1|val11|val12|key2|val2  |
+----+-----+-----+----+------+
|2   |two  |two  |two |second|
|1   |one  |one  |one |first |
+----+-----+-----+----+------+
```

But not sure how the execution has worked internally for the dataframe version though.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I need to do distinct on rdd and then create a DataFrame out of it. I have simplified your solution using this line. Thanks for the pointer!
val df3 = spark.createDataFrame(df2.rdd.distinct, df2.schema)